# Custom Template in PlayFramework multiproject

Tags: scala, templates, playframework, multi-module

I've a multi-module play app with a play module and other scala module and every thing works fine. I want to add a custom Twirl template and that's when problems arise. This is the [Multiproject structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iCO9N.png)

build.sbt:

```
name := """scalaplay"""

version := "1.0-SNAPSHOT"

lazy val root = (project in file(".")).enablePlugins(PlayScala).dependsOn(restfulapi,util).aggregate(restfulapi,util)
scalaVersion := "2.11.7"

/**
  * .dependsOn(util). will let us use element from dbmodule into apirestmodule. Specifically some element and structure
  * of the data model.
  *
  */

lazy val restfulapi = (project in file("modules/apirest")).enablePlugins(PlayScala).dependsOn(util).settings(scalaVersion:="2.11.7",
  libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
    cache,
    "org.scalatestplus.play" %% "scalatestplus-play" % "1.5.1" % Test
  )
)

lazy val util = (project in file("modules/dbmodule")).settings(scalaVersion:="2.11.7")

TwirlKeys.templateFormats += ("csv" -> "views.CsvFormat")
```

Part of apirest.routes:

```
    #processing premierLeague
    POST     /premier/match             controllers.PremierleagueController.insertMatch

    GET      /premier/matchs            controllers.PremierleagueController.getMatchGame

    GET     /assets/*file            controllers.Assets.versioned(path="/public", file: Asset)

    GET     /records                    controllers.HomeController.records
```

The action that use the template is in HomeController.scala:

```
......

 def records = Action {
    Ok(views.csv.records(Record.sampleRecords))
  }

.....
```

This is the result when I show my source:

```
[scalaplay] $ show twirlCompileTemplates::sourceDirectories
[info] restfulapi/compile:twirlCompileTemplates::sourceDirectories
[info]  List(/Users/ldipotet/scala/scalaplay/modules/apirest/app)
[info] root/compile:twirlCompileTemplates::sourceDirectories
[info]  List(/Users/ldipotet/scala/scalaplay/app)
```

And Here is my compilation Error when I try to compile the project:

```
[info] Compiling 22 Scala sources and 1 Java source to /Users/ldipotet/scala/scalaplay/modules/apirest/target/scala-2.11/classes...
[error] /Users/ldipotet/scala/scalaplay/modules/apirest/app/controllers/HomeController.scala:72: object csv is not a member of package views
[error]     Ok(views.csv.records(Record.sampleRecords))
[error]              ^
[error] one error found
[error] (restfulapi/compile:compileIncremental) Compilation failed
[error] Total time: 6 s, completed 24-jul-2017 17:18:11
```

For more info the same Custom template compile and works in a single playframework project

Answer (score 0):

The problem was the reference to the Custom Format File:

**TwirlKeys.templateFormats += ("csv" -> "views.CsvFormat")**

It was in the only built.sbt file placed at the root of the multi-project.

```
-rw-r--r--   1 ldipotet  staff     695 27 jul 01:23 build.sbt
drwxr-xr-x   5 ldipotet  staff     170 27 jul 01:16 conf
-rw-r--r--   1 ldipotet  staff  895312 18 jul 10:44 football.txt
drwxr-xr-x   3 ldipotet  staff     102 27 jul 01:43 logs
drwxr-xr-x   5 ldipotet  staff     170 12 jul 12:28 modules
-rw-r--r--   1 ldipotet  staff     191 20 jul 13:36 package.txt
drwxr-xr-x   6 ldipotet  staff     204 27 jul 01:16 project
drwxr-xr-x   5 ldipotet  staff     170  1 jun 12:24 public
-rw-r--r--   1 ldipotet  staff  175256 12 jul 16:54 regex.png
drwxr-xr-x  11 ldipotet  staff     374 27 jul 01:43 target
drwxr-xr-x   4 ldipotet  staff     136  5 jul 09:22 test
```

It was wrong because the compiler was trying to look for the format in the project where the template was. I meant in the project itself(basedir/modules/api rest) where was the template and there wasn't any reference there.

Solution: Create a build.sbt in the subproject **basedir/modules/apirest**
, where the Custom template is created:

basedir/modules/apirest/built.sbt

```
name := """apirest"""

TwirlKeys.templateFormats += ("csv" -> "views.CsvFormat")
```

And of course delete **TwirlKeys.templateFormats += ("csv" -> "views.CsvFormat")**  from the built.sbt at the root project.

No matter if it is single or multiproject, the reference must be placed in the project where the custom template is located.

Answer (score 0):

Answen given by @ldipotet actually solves the problem, but there are other ways too.

**1** Just moving the `TwirlKeys.templateFormats += ("csv" -> "views.CsvFormat")` inside the `restfulapi` definition in the main `build.sbt`, which would look like this:

```
...
lazy val restfulapi = (project in file("modules/apirest")).enablePlugins(PlayScala).dependsOn(util).settings(scalaVersion:="2.11.7",
  libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
    cache,
    "org.scalatestplus.play" %% "scalatestplus-play" % "1.5.1" % Test
  ),
  TwirlKeys.templateFormats += ("csv" -> "views.CsvFormat")
)
...
```

**2** If you are going to need the custom format in other subprojects, moving common settings to an object in a new `Common.scala` file (name it whatever you want) in the `basedir/project` directory:

```
import sbt._

object Common {
  val settings: Seq[Setting[_]] = Seq(
    TwirlKeys.templateFormats += ("csv" -> "views.CsvFormat")
  )
}
```

Then use Common object in subprojects `build.sbt`:

```
name := """apirest"""

Common.settings
```

See the [Play](https://playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/SBTSubProjects) and [SBT](https://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Multi-Project.html) documentation on subprojects for more details.